# AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no __call__ method

Tags: python

the first pass everything works fine, but the second run I get AttributeError: instance has no __ addinfourl call__ method, i don't know what's wrong

first pass 
True 
Status:OK

second pass File "D:\python\New Status\status.py", line 124, in  print mainstatus.bite() File "D:\python\New Status\status.py", line 109, in bite s = file("cc.beat") AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no call method

basically use it to check the status of a server and confirm that another process is active

```
    failure = True
    servestatus = False


    def log():
        a=open ("Status.failures","a")
        now = datetime.now()
        tiempo = str (now) +"  -  Error\n"
        a.write(tiempo)
        a.close ()

    class mainstatus(object):

        @staticmethod
        def xmlstatus():
            try:        
                file = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.110:9900/admin/xmlstatus?user=&password=')
                data = file.read()
                file.close()
                dom = parseString(data)
                xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('Status')[0].toxml()
                xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<Status>','').replace('</Status>','')
                if xmlTag == "<Status>OK</Status>":
                    stat = True
            except:
                stat= False
            return stat

        @staticmethod
        def hola():
            x = "test"
            return x

        @staticmethod
        def internet(url):
            try:
                response=urllib2.urlopen(url,timeout=1)
                return True
            except urllib2.URLError as err: pass
            return False

        @staticmethod
        def heartbeat():
            a=open ("heart.beat","w")
            now = datetime.now()
            tiempo = str (now.minute)
            a.write(tiempo)
            a.close ()

        @staticmethod
        def push(mensaje):
            #Miguel
            conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
            conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
              urllib.urlencode({
                "token": "",
                "user": "",
                "message": mensaje,
              }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
            conn.getresponse()
            #Gerswin
            conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("api.pushover.net:443")
            conn.request("POST", "/1/messages.json",
              urllib.urlencode({
                "token": "",
                "user": "",
                "message": mensaje,
              }), { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
            conn.getresponse()

        @staticmethod
        def colam():
            cola = 0
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk("\\\\Server0\\smsdata\\Q"):
                    for file in files:    
                            if file.endswith('.req'):
                                    cola += 1
        @staticmethod
        def wol():
            HOST = "192.168.1.1"
            user = "root"
            password = "16745665"
            tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
            tn.read_until("login: ")
            tn.write(user + "\n")
            if password:
                tn.read_until("Password: ")
                tn.write(password + "\n")
            tn.write("/usr/sbin/wol -i 192.168.1.255 -p 7 00:11:25:36:08:FE\n")
            tn.write("exit\n")
            tn.read_all()

        @staticmethod
        def bite(): 
            now = datetime.now()
            tiempo = (now.minute)
            s = file("cc.beat")
            status = int(s.readline())
            s.close()
            vivo = tiempo - status    
            if (vivo > 0):
                return False
            else:
                return True

    count = 5
    print "Server Status Check: Runing..."

    while (count < 9):

        time.sleep(2)
        print mainstatus.bite()
        pulso = True
        if pulso == False:
            #os.startfile('check.exe')
            print "activa"
        else:
            pass
        status = mainstatus.internet("http://192.168.1.110:9900")
        mainstatus.heartbeat()
        if status == True:
          if   mainstatus.xmlstatus() == True:
              print '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bStatus:OK',

              if failure == True:
                  accion = os.system('net stop "NowSMS"')
                  file = urllib2.urlopen('http://sql.gerswin.com/status.php?status=OK')
                  data = file.read()
                  file.close()
                  failure = False

              if mainstatus.colam() >= 20 and servestatus == False:
                  accion = os.system('net start "NowSMS"')
                  mainstatus.push("Server Overload, Server 2 Running")
                  servestatus = True
              else:
                  if mainstatus.colam() < 20 and servestatus == True:
                      mainstatus.push("Stoping Server 2")
                      accion = os.system('net stop "NowSMS"')
                      servestatus = False
                      file = urllib2.urlopen('http://sql.gerswin.com/status.php?status=OK')
                      data = file.read()
                      file.close()

          else:
              print '\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bStatus: Modem Failure',
              mainstatus.wol()        
              if servestatus == False:
                  accion = os.system('net start "NowSMS"')
                  mainstatus.push("Modem Failure, Server 2 Running")
                  log()
                  file = urllib2.urlopen('http://sql.gerswin.com/status.php?status=2')
                  data = file.read()
                  file.close()
                  servestatus = True

        else:
            print "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bStatus: Fallo Server",
            mainstatus.wol()
            if servestatus == False:           
                accion = os.system('net start "NowSMS"')
                file = urllib2.urlopen('http://192.168.1.110:9900?ok=no')
                data = file.read()
                file.close()
                log()
                mainstatus.push("Server Failure, Server 2 Running")
                servestatus = True
```

Comment: Your question title and question content have different error messages; can you please include the *full* traceback? Format it just like you did with the code, with an indented block.

Comment: first pass
True
Status:OK
second pass
File "D:\python\New Status\status.py", line 124, in <module>
    print mainstatus.bite()
  File "D:\python\New Status\status.py", line 109, in bite
    s = file("cc.beat")
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no __call__ method

Comment: You should [edit] your question to add that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the global variable `file` to store the result of a `urllib2.urlopen()` call, twice. But you are also expecting to use it as the built-in [`file()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> file('/dev/random')
<open file '/dev/random', mode 'r' at 0x10c8ee660>
>>> file = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')
>>> file('/dev/random')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no __call__ method
```

Don't do that. Don't shadow built-ins with your own variable name, *and* don't use `file()`. Use the [`open()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) instead.

```
>>> open('/dev/random')
<open file '/dev/random', mode 'r' at 0x10c8ee6f0>
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen('http://stackoverflow.com')
```